# if statement does not work properly?

Tags: java

I wrote this piece of code of simple if statement
and the out put is not it should be
it gives

What is your Gender?
male
male
The user did not answer the Question.

**strong text**
public static void main(String args[]) {

```
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your Gender?");
    String gender = userInput.nextLine();

    System.out.println(gender);

    if (gender == "Male" || gender == "male") {
        System.out.println("Go to Room M1.");
    } else if (gender == "Female" || gender == "female") {
        System.out.println("Go to Room F1.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The user did not answer the Question.");
    }

    userInput.close();
}
```

Comment: there are 10 kinds of people. Those who know binary and those who dont. Nice Name

Comment: you are using `==` and it is a reference comparison not a value one. You should use `equals`, see [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more info

Comment: Just FYI, you can use equalsIgnoreCase() and remove the OR condition

Answer (score 0):

use "Male".equals(gender) instead of == .
similarly for others

Comment: you can accept the answer if its the correct answer